# Primefaces comondButton redirect stopped working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code to redirect me to another web page:

```
<p:commandButton value="RegisterMe"
                    action="registration?faces-redirect=true">
                </p:commandButton>
```

It was working some minutes ago and it stopped... I did not change anything but the button does not redirect me to registration page. Do you know what can happened? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the button does not redirect me to registration page`. Well, what's doing right now, then?

Comment: That is the problem, nothing happened when i click the button.

Comment: Button is fine, problem is outside of this code. Impossible to help without more info. Try cleaning and building

Comment: There might be some validation errors behind the scenes not showing up in your screen?

Comment: Is there at least a `h:form` wrapped arround your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ajax="false"` attribute in `p:commandButton`. For more sure, there is no `update model process`, you can use `immediate="true"`.